# Apply change to a folder in all git branches

Tags: git, branch

Im updating a static image resource that was being cached across a few branches. Is there a way I can make a commit of the new folder in each branch without checking in/out each branch?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can script the operation to some degree.  Make the change in one branch and then, assuming that the commit ID for that change is `$COMMIT`, do this:

```
for BRANCH in branch1 branch2 branch3 ...; do
    git checkout $BRANCH
    git cherry-pick $COMMIT
done
```